# German term for 'Frenemy'?

Tags: single-word-request, slang, informal

Has a German term for the English word *frenemy* been developed?

I found a definition through Google:

> Eine Person, die nur vorgibt ein Freund zu sein.

I would say this is accurate, however I'm wondering if any slang is being used in current German for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This blend or [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of *"friend"* and *"enemy"* is only rarely found in contemporary German media, but it may be the starting point of a new loanword that will eventually make its way into common usage over time:

> Vielleicht lernen ja alle Beteiligten etwas daraus. Etwa, dass auf Dauer Kompromissbereitschaft unter geschäftlichen **Frenemys** wertvoll ist - Frenemy, weil Google eben sowohl Friend als auch Enemy der Verlage ist, je nach Sichtweise. Was soll da helfen, außer miteinander zu reden? <sup>[Süddeutsche Digital 1. März 2013](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/digital/beschlossenes-leistungsschutzrecht-ein-gesetz-das-nur-verlierer-kennt-1.1613312)</sup>

Until then we may use a different wording to define friends who in reality are enemies or rivals:

**Examples:**

> Seine **sogenannten Freunde**  sind nur auf sein Geld aus.
> **Schöne Freunde** hast du da, die dich immer zu Unsinn anstiften.
> Mit dem Ruhm kamen auch eine Reihe **angeblicher Freunde**.
> Ihre vielen **"Freunde"** werden ihr zunehmend eine Last.

We do also find the translation *"falsche Freunde"*. I feel this is correct but we need to take care to not confuse this with the term *"false friends"* used in translations.

Answer (score 3):

The German definition of frenemy (or frienemy), namely that of a "pretend friend", that you found appears to be how many Germans interpret this English [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau_word).

One German blogger even [started a blog](http://freund-feind.blogspot.de/) around this definition!

However, English speakers may also use it to refer to "... someone who really is your friend but is also a rival" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenemy)).

You can find this alternative meaning used probably as often in German, too:

> Fabio Stassi fesselt in seinem Schachroman beide Rivalen schicksalhaft
>   aneinander: "Wäre Capablanca nicht auf die Welt gekommen, hätte
>   Aljechin keinen Rivalen gehabt"; umgekehrt wäre Capablanca nichts ohne
>   seinen hassgeliebten **Freundfeind** gewesen. Source: [Pfälzischer
>   Merkur](http://www.pfaelzischer-merkur.de/region/kultur/art27524,2927528)

So as the quote from *Merkur* shows, when you are thinking of a person as a frienemy in the sense of someone you love to hate,  use *Freundfeind*. (Make sure, though, to surround it with sufficient explanatory context as it is not a common word.)

Update: According to [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Freundfeind), the first writer to use the word may have been Lionel Feuchtwanger (b. 1884 in Munich - d. 1958 in Los Angeles). It is not tied to a specific geographic area. (DWDS lists eleven uses in articles in *Die Zeit*, a weekly newspaper edited in Hamburg but published nationwide, alone.)

Comment: I've never heard about this artificial word, `falscher Freund` is the one.

Comment: nice - [*"Freundfeind"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Freundfeind) already found it's way to Duden.

Comment: Dear falkb, this question, in case it escaped your notice, starts from an "artificial" word -- fr(i)enemy -- in the first place. (Though the technically accurate description, as I said, is _portmanteau_). It may be that you had not heard of _Freundfeind_ before but now that you have, feel free to find more instances of its use in the German language; I certainly have been familiar with it for a long time.

Comment: So `Freundfeind` seems to be a regionally known term. It's totally not used here and I had just replied `Hä?` ;) Duden rates its commonness with the lowest value also.